# failed to exec /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/clang: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, clang

Xcode 5 breaks my compilation script. I suspect because clang is now located directly in /usr/bin instead of its usual location. However, I'm not sure how I can tell this to gcc. Any tips would be much appreciated. I am compiling for iOS.

```
   CPPFLAGS= -arch i686 --sysroot=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk -fno-short-wchar -fno-short-enums -miphoneos-version-min=4.2.1
    CXXFLAGS= -arch i686 --sysroot=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk -fno-short-wchar -fno-short-enums -miphoneos-version-min=4.2.1
    CFLAGS=
    gcc -Iinclude  -arch i686 --sysroot=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk -fno-short-wchar -fno-short-enums -miphoneos-version-min=4.2.1   -c -o src_c/stem_UTF_8_danish.o src_c/stem_UTF_8_danish.c
    gcc: failed to exec /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/clang: No such file or directory
    make: *** [src_c/stem_UTF_8_danish.o] Error 71
```

**Update.** I was able to repeat the problem by directly calling gcc from the iPhoneSimulator usr/bin with no arguments.

```
tim$ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform//Developer/us                                    r/bin/gcc
gcc: failed to exec /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/clang: No such file or directory
```

I was able to get it to compile by using clang from /usr/bin with the appropriate sysroot. but is this equivalent?

Comment: There really isn't enough information to debug this issue. the `/usr/bin` wrappers simply invoke the default applications as specified by `xcode-select` - is the clang binary under `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin` ??

Comment: You've got something interfering with your compilation. What does xcrun -find clang report? it should be showing something like: `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang`

Comment: How did you fix it? I am facing same problem, the command line tools of Xcode are installed too, but still I am facing this problem

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the same problem when I upgraded to Xcode 5.1  When I ran "xcrun -find clang", it said "You have not agreed to the XCode license agreements.  You must agree to both Xcode license agreements below in order to use Xcode."  It spewed out the agreements and gave me an opportunity to agree, which I did.  And that fixed the problem.  Go figure.

Cheers - Ed